# npm start script with babel-node and dotenv

Tags: javascript, babeljs, package.json, nodemon, npm-scripts

I have this script which works well

```
"start": "nodemon -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js"
```

I want use babel-node instead node. So there is the new script:

```
"start": "nodemon -x babel-node --presets=env -r dotenv/config -- src/index.js"
```

But I get this error

```
[nodemon] starting `babel-node --presets=env -r dotenv/config src/index.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pathTo/dotenv/config'
```

Can you help ?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -r node_modules/dotenv/config index.js"
```

Answer (score 3):

This [issues](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/10871) existed for a short time in babel.
@babel/node cannot seem to resolve node modules, when using [--require flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module)

```
  "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -r ./node_modules/dotenv/config src/index.js"
```

This issue has now been [resolved](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/10871).
Allow -r from node_modules with @babel/node

```
  "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -r dotenv/config src/index.js"
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some explanation around your solution.

Comment: This is just a copy of the excepted answer, how would that help?

Comment: For the SO platform to work correctly, existing Answers should be upvoted, not duplicated. If there is a typo, either add Comment below the post, or suggest. The SO platform operates in a different way than forums do. But that is part of the value of this platform. Each platform has is strengths. Also, when referencing another post (Q or A), it needs to be linked to, as there is no other easy way to tell which post you're referring to. The order of Answers changes, as the number of Answers, and votes for each changes. It also depends on the "sort" order each user has chosen. Also, read below..

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. Be sure to supplement your code with explanations &/or quotes from & links to source documentation.

Comment: That said, welcome to SO. We look forward to your future contributions. Please read the top posts in Asking and Answering sections of https://StackOverflow.com/help for additional guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check pathTo/dotenv/confit resource path.
I know Babel node bundle file has very strict path rule.

Answer (score 0):

yes,

```
"start": "nodemon -x babel-node -r node_modules/dotenv/config --presets=env src/index.js"
```

seems to work

EDIT In fact this definitively does not works

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a reasonably old thread, but here is what worked for me. Full disclosure, I don't really know *why* this works, but it did. Files condensed for relevancy.

#### Environment

```
Windows 10
Node 10.13.0
NPM 6.4.1
Babel 7.2.3
Nodemon 1.18.9
Dotenv 6.2.0
```

---

#### package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon src/index.js -- --require node_modules/dotenv/config"
    }
}
```

---

#### nodemon.json:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the npm package "env-cmd" for this situation.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd --file ./path/to/.env nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"
  }
```